# Should a RESTful GET collection API return content of elements

Tags: rest, get

I have an entity stored in the backend which translates to the json format as,

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "name": "test",
  "key": "test1",
  "description": "",
  "models": [
    {
      content
    },
    {
      content
    }
  ]
}
```

So when i want to retrieve the list of elements using the api

```
GET /elements
```

Should i return the elements metadata only(id, name, descriptions) or should  also include the content(models[])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally

`GET /elements`

would return a list of complete entities.

You could add another endpoint:

`GET /elements/meta` or `GET /elements?mode=meta`

which would return a List of the metadata only.